# Google Sheets: how to prepare data for pasting

Tags: google-sheets

How to prepare the data on HTML page so that it can be copied and pasted onto the Google Sheets while maintaining the text formatting (bold, italic, web links, ect.).
If I do formatting with html tags, then it is not saved when pasting.
Can it be possible to generate some text in the markdown or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

**Try using the `=IMPORTHTML()` function and formatting the columns/rows in the spreadsheet the way you want them to appear**, rather than pulling in that information from the HTML file.

If the formatting needs to be dynamic based on the HTML then that is not possible with a simple formula and you may need to look into AppScripts (though I’m not sure it’s possible with that either).